# What is the eqivalent of String.valueOf() in Kotlin?

Tags: java, string, kotlin

What is the equivalent of String.valueOf() in Kotlin?
I want to convert the java code in kotlin code.

```
var count = 0
for(i in 0 until rings.length){
    if(rings.contains("R"+ String.valueOf(i)) && rings.contains("G"+ String.valueOf(i)) && rings.contains("B"+ String.valueOf(i)))
       count++
}
 return count
```

I checked kotlin documentation, but I don't undertand too much. It's kind of confusing.

Comment: you can use the toString() function to convert a value to a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String.valueOf(X) converts X object to a string by the call of X.toString() or returns "null" if X is null.

Your code tries to convert i to string and i can't be null, so you can replace it to .toString()

```
rings.contains("R"+i.toString()) && rings.contains("G"+i.toString()) && rings.contains("B"+i.toString())
```

Kotlin allows you to concat string with object of any type or null, so the expression can be simplified:

```
rings.contains("R"+i) && rings.contains("G"+i) && rings.contains("B"+i)
```

And the other variant is the string interpolation:

```
rings.contains("R$i") && rings.contains("G$i") && rings.contains("B$i")
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using [Kotlin's string templates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/strings.html#string-templates) `"$i"`

```
"R"+ String.valueOf(i)
```

becomes:

```
"R$i"
```